# Raster Data to Polygon

Tags: raster, polygon, vector

1. I need to "translate" raster information to a set of polygons.
2. The raster to polygon tool will not work.
3. I created a fishnet with the same resolution of the raster and converted it to polygons.
4. I now have a "Grid" of polygons with the same resolution as the raster.
5. I would like to populate the attribute table with the value of the cells in the raster data

In the images below you will see my "Grid" of polygons and my raster with the "grid" overlay-ed.
Now how do i get the raster values into the attribute table of the polygons?

Any Suggestions?[image: "Grid" Of Polygons][image: Raster with "Grid" of polygons overlayed]

Comment: What GIS software and version are you using?  Please edit this important information for potential answerers into your Question.

Answer (score 1):

Join attributes by location in QGIS should do it. Install the Ftools plugin:
[image]